# Pull PDFs from VARBINARY(MAX) javascript:__doPostBack

Tags: sql-server, pdf, varbinary, dopostback

I have managed to pull ~300K .pdf files from an old MOSS 2007. 
I've now found out that there is another database that contains ~400K .pdf files, I've full access to the database. Unlike the MOSS 2007 server, those files are stored in a VARBINARY(MAX) column.

I've created a new table and have successfully imported a .pdf to a varbinary column and then pulled it back.
When I try to do the same with the original table the file is corrupted (I open the .pdf file with notepad++ and see `"II*     þ             ½        "` etc. instead of a valid .pdf which begins `"%PDF-1.1 %âãÏÓ 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj"`

When I look at the Sharepoint and select the scrambled .pdf it opens correctly. "default.aspx" is the filename, I can download the file and rename the file to default.pdf and it works perfectly.

The link which says "Select" to one of those files are: `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_4230fef8_e3e9_4be5_906b_23ab6096189d$ctl00$gridAnsok','Select$0')">Select</a>`

Can I see what the __doPostBack actually queries?

Comment: Is the byte following `II*` a `00`? If so it's an Intel ordered (little-endian) TIFF image, not a PDF.

Comment: OMG, you have saved my life. How did you even know this? THANK YOU!

Comment: I've been doing software development since the 1980s. One of my early projects was to write import/export plugins for over 30 different graphic file formats. Apparently some of that stuff sticks around for life. :)